# How to pass list of grep/regex commands to R function

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of roughly 50 somewhat complicated grepl commands strings that I would like to pass to a function in R.  I am using these functions to subset a dataframe.  Here is an example of 2 of the commands:

```
t <- subDF[grepl("(extreme|abnormal|unseasonably|unusually|record|excessive) (heat|warm|high temp)",subDF$EVTYPE),]

t <- subDF[grepl("fl(oo)?d",subDF$EVTYPE) & !grepl("flash",subDF$EVTYPE) & !grepl("(tidal|beach|(c(oa)?sta?l))(/tidal)? ?(flood)",subDF$EVTYPE),]
```

So, in this example I would like to pass pass these 2 grepl commands to a function that will do this subsetting on dataframe subDF (plus pass the other 48 or so).

Any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that uses `quote` to create two unevaluated `grepl` calls.  They are then evaluated in an `sapply` call with `eval`.

```
> fruits <- c("one apple", "two pears", "three bananas")
> QQ <- list(q1 = quote(grepl("(one)|(apple)", fruits)),
             q2 = quote(grepl("apple", fruits) | grepl("bananas|one", fruits)))
> sapply(QQ, function(x) fruits[eval(x)])
#$q1
#[1] "one apple"
# 
#$q2
#[1] "one apple"     "three bananas"
```

A look at `QQ`

```
#$q1
#grepl("(one)|(apple)", fruits)
#
#$q2
#grepl("apple", fruits) | grepl("bananas|one", fruits)
```

Something else that is useful is

```
> as.list(quote(grepl("one|apple", fruits)))
# [[1]]
# grepl
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "one|apple"
# 
# [[3]]
# fruits
```

With this, you can replace the regular expression (or call or `x`) in every iteration by way of `[[` indexing.

Comment: Thanks, made heavy use of quote() and got it all done!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're after `Reduce`. Using the iris dataset as an example:

```
mygrep <- function(x, df) df[grepl(x, df$Species), ]
pat <- c("setosa", "(setosa|virginica)")

Reduce(mygrep, pat, iris, right=TRUE)
```